# anchor links break inside angular app even when not inside a controller?

Tags: angularjs, hyperlink, anchor

I'm using anchor links in my page. I'm using the following scheme of anchor links:

```
<a href="#link">
<div id="link">
```

When inside an angular app the anchor links redirect to a slahsed url that doesnt work.
this is what the link redirects to /mypage#/link
this what it should under normal circumstances /mypage#link 
using the /mypage#link directly works as usual.

Taking the anchor code chunk outside the angular app also works. Only within the angular app it breaks working showing the above behavior where it adds a slash.

Can somebody point what am I doing wrong?

Comment: try using ng-href instead of href inside angular app. If this does not help then please post a demo of your app.